# Arrays of unknown type

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Why is the expression `?[]` illegal? I don't understand why it is any more suspect than `T[]`. I get that there are problems with generic array creation, so I see why things like `new T[]` and `new ?[3]` are disallowed, but I don't see what's wrong with `?[]`. It would be nice, for example, to be able to have a method signature like `void method(?[] arr)`. What's wrong with this?

Also, what is the preferred way to write a method taking an array of unknown type? Should you use

```
public void method(Object[] arr)
```

in preference to

```
public <T> void method(T[] arr)
```

or is this an exception to the usual rule that you should avoid type parameters in method signatures if the type parameter appears only once?

Comment: Using `<T>` is useful if you use `T` more than once, like `public <T> T method(T[] arr, T foo)`.

Comment: Using the generic T can also be helpful for narrowing, as in `<T extends Number>`. You can't do that with Object.

Comment: `T` is a type declared, either at class level or function level. `?` is a wildcard, which is never actually given specific value, thus it's not an actual type you can use

Comment: I don't get the question. '?' is the wildcard character used to **define** a type parameter, not a replacement for a type parameter itself, so you cannot use a question mark where you'd usually use a type parameter!

Comment: I get all of these points, but they don't really address the question. List<?> is allowed but ?[] is not. What's the difference?

Comment: It is also not allowed to have `void method(? param)`. Same reason: '?' is not a type.

Comment: With `List`, you are *passing* a type, which is the resolved at **run-time**. With a regular array, you are *declaring* a type that's resolved at **compile time**. You cannot declare a wildcard and expect it to be resolved at compile-time, thus the error you're getting

Comment: I don't really get any of these objections. All I am asking is why the signature void method(?[] arr) couldn't simply be interpreted in exactly the same way as the signature <T> void method(T[] arr). If you are saying the question doesn't make sense it follows that you don't think the signature <T> void method(T[] arr) makes sense either. @isnot2bad, the fact that you can't write void method(? param) either doesn't answer the question. Why can't you? Why could it not be treated the same as <T> void method(T param).

Comment: @pbabcdefp I've tried to explain this in my answer. You're mixing up type parameters and type arguments.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Your method might make somewhat sense how it is (whatever type is passed in, use that in place of all the question-marks). Try that while accepting 2 types `<K, V>`. Not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use

```
public void method(Object[] arr)
```

in preference to

```
public <T> void method(T[] arr)
```

because they both accept the same set of potential arguments, and the first one is simpler and has less type parameters.

> Why is the expression `?[]` illegal?

Syntactically, because the left side of `[]` must be an actual type. Linguistically, it's because it is unnecessary, you can use `Object[]` instead.

In general, whenever you want to do something like `(? extends X)[]`, in your mind, just transform it to `X[]`. And similarly, whenever you want to use something like `? extends X` as a standalone type, think of `X` instead.

For generics type arguments, `? extends X` is needed because generic types are not covariant (`List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<B>` even if `A` is a subtype of `B`). However, array types are covariant (`A[]` is a subtype of `B[]` if `A` is a subtype of `B`), so having `(? extends X)[]` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, you make a good case. It's the linguistic point I was getting at. I agree that ?[] is unnecessary, but generics are so complicated I think it would have been worth enabling it to make them more consistent and easier to understand. For example if you create a generic class MyClass<T> with an instance method foo that returns a T[], commonsense dictates that if you invoke foo on a MyClass<?> you ought to get a ?[]. In fact, IntelliJ actually lists the return type as ?[] (I don't know about eclipse). It's confusing and strange that you can't write ?[] in your code.

Comment: Also, while you _can_ always use `Object[]` when you'd want to use `?[]`, it's not always at all obvious how. For example, if you want to get rid of the type parameter in the signature `<T> void foo(Set<T[]> set)` you have to write `void foo(Set<? extends Object[]> set)`, which is really convoluted - `void foo(Set<?[]> set)` would be much clearer.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: That's a separate issue. For example, `<T> void foo(Set<List<T>> set)` cannot be turned into `void foo(Set<List<?>> set)`; the most similar is `void foo(Set<? extends List<?>> set)`

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it and you're right. `foo(Set<List<?>> set)` won't accept a `Set<List<String>>`. I should probably just give up trying to understand generics! Is there any point in the signature `void foo(Set<List<?>> set)`? Will it accept any concrete types at all?

Comment: @pbabcdefp: Yes, `HashSet<List<?>>` is a concrete type. It is a set that can contain different types of lists at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up type parameters and type arguments!

- A type parameter is [a placeholder for a type argument](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ001).
- A type argument is [a reference type or a wildcard that is used for instantiation of a generic type or a reference type used for instantiation of a generic method](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ001).

Consider the following example of generic type `List`:

```
interface List<T> {
    void add(T element);
    int size();
    T get(int index);
}
```

Here, `T` is the **type parameter**. It is a placeholder for the 'real' type, that is 'filled in' when the generic type is instantiated. You can use this placeholder inside the implementation of the generic type, e.g. to declare a variable, or as a type argument for another generic type:

```
class LinkedList<T> implements List<T> {
    private Node<T> head; // here, T is the type argument of E in Node<E>
    ...
}

class Node<E> {
    private E element; // here, E is a placeholder for the 'real' type
    ...
}
```

A type parameter is a formal parameter like `element` is the formal parameter of the method `add` in the example above. It is just a placeholder for the value that is specified at runtime!

Now let's use the generic type:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Here, `String` is the **type argument** that replaces the type parameter `T` of the generic type.

The wildcard ('?') is also some sort of type argument, saying that the concrete type is not known (and irrelevant). So you can use it when instantiating a generic type:

```
List<?> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Again, `?` is a **type argument**, so you cannot use it like a **type parameter**!