# Unbounded wildcard generic array from supplier in enum

Tags: java, generics, enums, java-8

I have enum that has constructor with generics. This constructor expect `Class<T>` and `Supplier<T[]>` as parameter:

```
private <T> Foo(final Class<T> clazz, final Supplier<T[]> arg)
```

Now I would like to store `arg` in member variable in enum. Bacause generics are not supported on enum level, I have to use unbounded wildcard:

```
public enum Foo {
    private final Supplier<?> arg;
}
```

Parameter type from constructor (`Supplier<T[]>`) doesen't match to member variable (`Supplier<?>`). For this I need something like `Supplier<?[]>` or `Supplier<? extends Array>`. Both are invalid. Are there possibilities in Java to store this wildcard generic array?

All together in one enum:

```
public enum Foo {
    BAR(String.class, () -> new String[] { "A", "B", "C" });

    private final Class<?> clazz;
    private final Supplier<?> arg;
    // private final Supplier<?[]> arg;
    // private final Supplier<? extends Array> arg;

    private <T> Foo(final Class<T> clazz, final Supplier<T[]> arg) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    public Object[] getArgs() {
        return arg.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that `?[]` feels like it ought to be legal code. (See this similar question I asked a few weeks ago  [Arrays of unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810671/arrays-of-unknown-type)).

However I was informed that it is unnecessary as you can always use `Object[]`. Unlike `List`s, arrays are covariant, so any array of objects of any type is an `Object[]`.

You can use 
`Supplier<? extends Object[]>` 
for your purposes.